# MS-Access SQL Query - Filtering by date

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am trying to write up a Microsoft Access query that will return all of the data in a table where the assigned "Due By" date is within a day.

Meaning, when I come into the office in the AM, I should be able to run this query to see what was due yesterday and what is due today. Here is an example of the data:

```
 | ID | JobName                 | DueBy     |
 |----|-------------------------|-----------|
 | 1  | Sergio Pizza            | 5/5/2018  |
 | 2  | Hopkins Hospital        | 9/1/2018  |
 | 3  | Perry Hall High School  | 9/25/2018 |
 | 4  | Parkville High School   | 9/24/2018 |
 | 5  | Jim's House             | 9/24/2018 |
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT tblBid.*
FROM tblBid
WHERE (((tblBid.Due_By)>=(Now()-2)));
```

Which works in returning the **correct** dataset:

```
 | ID | JobName                 | DueBy     |
 |----|-------------------------|-----------|
 | 3  | Perry Hall High School  | 9/25/2018 |
 | 4  | Parkville High School   | 9/24/2018 |
 | 5  | Jim's House             | 9/24/2018 |
```

However, why do I need to write NOW()-2 and not NOW()-1? Why do I have to go back two days? When I write NOW()-1 I only get ID 3 for Perry Hall High School

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get the results you expect with `WHERE tblBid.Due_By>=(Date()-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *DateDiff*:

```
SELECT tblBid.*
FROM tblBid
WHERE DateDiff("d", tblBid.Due_By, Date()) Between 1 and 0;
```

Comment: Hi, @Gustav. This seemed to do the trick, thank you. Could you potentially ellaborate on your answer a little bit, just about what DateDiff is and why it works here? Then I can mark it as the correct answer so it can best help other people :)

Comment: Here, DateDiff returns the difference in calendar days between the _recorded date_ (ignoring any time information) and _today's date_. You can replace "d" with other values to obtain the count of other intervals than days, say hours..

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Now()` function which returns the current date & time, the dates in your table don't have a time part making them 12AM of that date, thus before `Now() - 1`, you need to use the `Date()` function which returns the date at 12AM and then you can use it as `Date() - 1`

Comment: Could you please provide an example answer?

Comment: the query should be the same that you use just replace the `Now()` function with the `Date()` function.```SELECT tblBid.*
FROM tblBid
WHERE (((tblBid.Due_By)>=(Date()-2)));```